# RMagic gem require error. RMagick2.so cannot be opened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

**When I try the following in my controller,**

```
require 'RMagick'
```

**and running**

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake gems:install
```

**I am getting the following error.**

```
rake aborted!
libMagickCore.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.10.0/lib/RMagick2.so
```

When I checked, the file RMagick2.so is present in the directory.

ImageMagick is also installed.

```
identify --version
```

gives

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.4.8-10 2015-05-23 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Any solution to this issue?

Before, when I installed Imagemagick 6.5 version, it was saying RMagick is configured with ImageMagick 6.4.8. Can we change the configured version of ImageMagick in RMagick gem?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ImageMagick and RMagick so completely at a loss.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the logs of the error please

Comment: @CaffeineCoder The rake task is aborted as shown in the question. That is the only error I am getting.

Comment: Can you paste the output of this command - which convert

Comment: /usr/local/bin/convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is with the path -

convert is located at

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

It should be located at

```
/usr/bin/convert
```

Remove the one under bin and reinstall it , and the issue will be solved .

Comment: When reinstalled, convert is still located at /usr/local/bin/convert

Comment: See this for more details - http://serverfault.com/questions/385462/imagemagick-libmagickcore-so-2-not-found and this too http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15598

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :)

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and mine is in /usr/bin but linked to /etc/alternatives/convert